# Javascript to generate dynamic string of numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a requirement to write a function to generate the below dynamic string.

Here are some examples of what the output should look like for a function argument of 6, 5, and 4, respectively (Actually I am flexible with passing the argument).

> 123456789**1**123456789**2**123456789**3**123456789**4**123456789**5**123456789**6**
>
> 123456789**1**123456789**2**123456789**3**123456789**4**123456789**5**
>
> 123456789**1**123456789**2**123456789**3**123456789**4**

The length of the output will always be a multiple of 10.

Should I use normal JS arrays OR can I use some ready jQuery methods to acheive this ?

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/1349426/4229270, https://stackoverflow.com/a/5885493/4229270

Comment: testndtv did any of the answers help you?  don't think any of us have received any feedback

Comment: Yes, all of them seem to be PERFECT !! Giving the upvotes now. Thx a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I do it:

```js
function dynamic_string(val){
var strin =  "123456789"
var result = ""
for(var i = 1; i <= val; i++){
  result += strin;
  result += i;
}
console.log(result)
}

dynamic_string(6)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is the code, I think it will help you

```
function dynamicNumber(n){
var s="";
for(i=1;i<=n;i++){

s=s+"123456789"+i;
}
return s;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this.

```
function generateString(l) {
  var x = "123456789",
    t = "";
  for (i = 1; i < (l + 1); i++) {
    t += x + i;
  }
  return t;
}
```

Example below:

```js
function generateString(l) {
  var x = "123456789",
    t = "";
  for (i = 1; i < (l + 1); i++) {
    t += x + i;
  }
  return t;
}

console.log(generateString(6))
console.log(generateString(5))
console.log(generateString(4))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

What about (ES6):

```
function getString(amount) {

    let sNumber = '';
    for(let i=1;i<=amount;i++) {

        sNumber += '123456789' + i;
    }
    return sNumber;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
var nu=5;
for(var i=1;i<=nu;i++){

for(j=1;j<=9;j++){
console.log(j)
}
console.log(i)
}
```

[jsbin](https://jsbin.com/xetudab/1/edit?js,console)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this simple logic...

```
var str = '123456789';
var len=5;
var out = ''
for(var i=1;i<=len;i++){out+=str+i;}
console.log(out)
```